# request for a memeber of template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template class with two template arguments with the following constructor and member:

```
template <class T, class TCompare>
class MyClass {
...
public:
MyClass(TCompare compare);
void addElement(T newElement);
...
};
```

And I have a structure which overloads operator () for integer comparison:

```
struct IntegerLess {
    bool operator () {const int& a, const int& b) {
       if (a < b)
           return true;
       return false;
    }
};
```

I create an object of class 'MyClass' and try to use it:

```
MyClass<int, IntegerLess> myClassObject(IntegerLess());
myClassObject.addElement(10);
```

However, I got the following compile-time error:

```
error: request for member ‘addElement’ in ‘myClassObject’, which is of non-class type ‘MyClass<int, IntegerLess>(IntegerLess (*)())’
```

How can I correct it? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*the most vexing parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). You can fix the problem by throwing in an extra set of parentheses:

```
MyClass<int, IntegerLess> myClassObject((IntegerLess()));
//                                      ^             ^
```

Note that if you had passed an lvalue directly, there would have been no scope for this parse:

```
IntegerLess x;
MyClass<int, IntegerLess> myClassObject(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `IntegerLess` object separately:

```
IntegerLess comparator;
MyClass<int, IntegerLess> myClassObject(comparator);
myClassObject.addElement(10);
```

Alternatively, add parentheses like juanchopanza suggested.